# how to change the below format to json format using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dataformat

I want to convert this data format:

`"color;blue:36 ,red:27"`

to the following JSON format:

```
{
  "Record": [
    {
      "type": "color",
      "data": "blue",
      "total": "36"
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "data": "red",
      "total": "27"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is `color;blue:36 ,red:27` really the format you want to convert?

Comment: yes..i get data in this format and im looking to convert it to the above format..

Comment: do you have some more data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand the exact problem with the given input, but that should suffice:

```js
    var input = "color;blue:36 ,red:27";

    // Reassignment is bad, but will shorten the example
    input = input.split(";");

    var attributeName = input[0];

    // No length validations, also bad
    var attributes = input[1].split(",");

    var results = {"Record": attributes.map(function(a) {
        a = a.split(":");
        return {"type":attributeName,
            "data":a[0].trim(),
            "total": a[1].trim()}
    })};

    console.log(results)
```

Comment: Ah you won the race! :)

Answer (score 1):

This proposal splits the string first by semicolon for getting the `type` and the data, delimited by `' ,'`. Then split by colon for `data` and `total`.

```js
var data = 'color;blue:36 ,red:27',
    parts = data.split(';'),
    object = {
        Record: parts[1].split(' ,').map(function (a) {
            var p = a.split(':');
            return { type: parts[0], data: p[0], total: p[1] };
        })
    };

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: you gave answer and i didn't even understand question

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd do it

```js
var dataFormat = "color;blue:36 ,red:27"
var splitFormat = dataFormat.split(";");
var type = splitFormat[0];
var colors = splitFormat[1].split(",");
var results = [];
_.each(colors, function(color) {
console.log(color)  
  var obj = {
    "type": type,
    "data": color.split(":")[0],
    "total":color.split(":")[1]
  }
  results.push(obj);
});
var final = {
  "Result": results
};
$("#result").html(JSON.stringify(final));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```